# Dismissing view controller after timeout

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a modal view controller with two actions: Confirm and Cancel. If user taps on one of these two buttons, some things happen and the view controller is automatically dismissed.

I need to handle the case when the user doesn't perform any action within a time interval. In this case, view controller should be dismissed. I tried to add the following instruction inside the `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
// Timeout handling
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:10.0];
```

My `dismissViewController` selector is just as simple as the name suggest:

```
- (void)dismissViewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Anyway, when the time expires, my app crashes. I received the following errors from the console:

```
2015-12-29 12:57:00.082 Test[826:292764] *** Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView<NSTextContainerView> *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIFoundation/UIFoundation-432/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1551
2015-12-29 12:57:00.083 Test[826:292764] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'
```

Could someone please explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
```

Comment: The exact same thing happens.

Comment: If this didn't fix your problem, why did you accept it?